# Is binary serialization inherently unsafe?

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

Microsoft warns against using [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) (they write that there is no way to make the de-serialization safe).

> Applications should stop using BinaryFormatter as soon as possible,
> even if they believe the data they're processing to be trustworthy.

I don't want to use **XML** or **Json**-based solutions (which are what they refer to). I am concerned about file size and preserving the object graph.

If I were to write my own methods to traverse through my object graph and convert the objects to binary could that be made safely or is it something specifically with converting from binary that makes it inherently more dangerous that text?

Comment: What's the objection to Json/xml?

Comment: @Caius Jard primarily size/performance. Let me know if I can improve the question. Thanks

Comment: Size -> gzip it. Performance -> roll your own protocol. You should test whether either of these is actually an issue; for very high percentage of the word's systems, it clearly isn't; gzip'd (by the webserver) Json is incredibly common

Comment: To make binary serialization safe two things are required: 1.) the currently loaded types cannot be exploited for attacks, and 2.) it should not be allowed to load assemblies during the deserialization. `BinaryFormatter` uses violates 2.), which is a huge security risk because it makes possible to run any code. 1.) is a bit trickier because there can be undiscovered exploits but .NET Core disabled `[Serializable]` on many harmful types. Feel free to try [my serializer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization), which is pretty fast and also supports safe mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Are there binary (non-XML and non-JSON) alternatives to `BinaryFormatter`?

This question feels like it leads to answers that will be more opinion-based.

I'm sure there are a lot of libraries out there, but perhaps the best known alternative is [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) (protobuf).  It's a Google library, so it gets plenty of development and attention.  However, not everyone agrees that using protobuf for generic binary serialization is the best thing to do.

Follow this [discussion about BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29976) on the github for dotnet if you want more info; it discusses the general problem with `BinaryFormatter`, as well as using protobuf as an alternative.

### Can I create my own secure binary serialization system?

Yes.  That said, the real question should be: 'is it worth my time to do so?'

See this link for the wind-down plan for `BinaryFormatter`:
https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/141/commits/bd0a0661f9d248ed31a354d27ad026efd6719690

At the very bottom you will find:

> **Why not make `BinaryFormatter` safe for untrusted payloads?**
>
> The `BinaryFormatter` protocol works by specifying the values of an
> object's raw instance fields. In other words, the entire point of
> `BinaryFormatter` is to bypass an object's typical constructor and to
> use private reflection to set the instance fields to the contents that
> came in over the wire. Bypassing the constructor in this fashion means
> that the object cannot perform any validation or otherwise guarantee
> that its internal invariants are satisfied. One consequence of this is
> that `BinaryFormatter` is unsafe even for seemingly innocuous types
> such as `Exception` or `List<T>` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`,
> regardless of the actual types of *T*, *TKey*, or *TValue*.
> Restricting deserialization to a list of allowed types will not
> resolve this issue.

The security issue isn't with binary serialization as a concept; the issue is with how `BinaryFormatter` was implemented.

You could design a secure binary deserialization system, if you wanted.  If you have very few messages being sent, and you can tightly control which types are deserialized, perhaps it's not too much effort to make a secure system.

However, for a system flexible enough to handle many different use cases (e.g. many different types that can be deserialized), you may find that it takes a lot of effort to build in enough safety checks.

---

FWIW, you likely will never reach the performance levels of `BinaryFormatter` with a secure system that offers the same widespread utility (use cases), since `BinaryFormatter`'s speed comes (in part) from *having very few safety features*.  You *might* approach such performance levels with a targeted, small system with a narrow set of use cases.

Comment: _"even for seemingly innocuous types"_ - `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` actually implements `ISerializable` so it could validate the input after all (but it doesn't do that). And a [custom serializer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) (disclaimer: written by me) can natively support common collection types that makes their serialization both secure and very [compact](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T7BUyB) . Of course, the default field-based serialization should be avoided if some field can have invalid values. See also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50909